# Meteor + IOS + Parse? How do I connect IOS app securely to MongoDB on Meteor app?

Tags: ios, mongodb, meteor

I am building a web application using Meteor. Now, I need to build an ios app, which accesses the same mongodb as the Meteor app securely (user needs to login etc.) What is the best approach to do that? Can I use Parse (http://Parse.com) service to do that. If yes, how do I synch my Meteor mongodb changes to Parse and then push it to the iOS app.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm looking to potentially do the same thing.